# Where does thorium come from in Kittens Game?

Tags: kittens-game

I recently started playing kittens game again and now I have some thorium? How do you create thorium? I'm just a monkey pushing buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thorium is created by refining Uranium in the Workshop Tab.

I believe you need to research Thorium Technology before being able to get Thorium.

Comment: Oh yeah, lol I should have known

Answer (score 0):

It will show up in the workshop once you have Uranium (typically generated by Accellerators in early game or traded with the Dragons)